# ARC (In Elixir app) won't upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir

I'm having a problem configuring ARC to work in my app.  First, when I use the configuration as described below, the file is loaded into local storage.  If I add the line

```
def __storage, do: Arc.Storage.Local
```

to `uploader.ex`, I get an error -- not too informative: "something went wrong."  Also, when I try a direct upload, here is what happens:

```
iex(2)> Avatar.store("/Users/carlson/Downloads/jupiter.jpg")
{:ok, "jupiter.jpg"}
```

However, when I check my S3 bucket, I find only a few old items.  And nothing is added to local storage

1. CONFIG

   ## files: config.dev, config.prod

   ```
   config :arc,
    storage: Arc.Storage.S3,
    bucket: "noteimages"

   config :ex_aws,
    access_key_id: System.get_env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
    secret_access_key: System.get_env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
   ```
2. MIX.EXS

   ## file: mix.exs:

   ```
   defp deps do
     [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
      {:comeonin, "~> 2.0"},
      {:mnemonix, "~> 0.2.0"},
      {:timex, "~>3.0"},
      {:timex_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
      {:benchfella, "~> 0.3.2"},
      {:json, "~> 1.0"},
      {:joken, "~> 1.1"},
      {:arc, "~> 0.8.0"},
      {:arc_ecto, "~> 0.4", override: true},
      {:shared, in_umbrella: true},
      {:ex_aws, "~> 1.1"},
      {:poison, "~> 2.0"},
      {:httpoison, "~> 0.11"},
      {:hackney, "~> 1.6"}]
   end
   ```
3. S3 Bucket policy

   ```
   {  
      "Version":"2012-10-17",
      "Id":"Policy1493266128611",
      "Statement":[  
         {  
            "Sid":"Stmt1493266101437",
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Principal":{  
               "AWS":"*"
            },
            "Action":"s3:GetObject",
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::noteimages/*"
         }
      ]
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you get an more information from the console? This may not be the issue, but it looks like the [config for ex_aws](https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws#getting-started) needs to be a list for `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely the use of the following in your config.

```
config :ex_aws,
 access_key_id: System.get_env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
 secret_access_key: System.get_env("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
```

You are binding the environment variables at compile time, not run time. If you look at the [Arc Readme](https://github.com/stavro/arc), you will see the following syntax for your config

```
{:system, "AWS_S3_BUCKET"}
```

So, try this:

```
config :ex_aws,
 access_key_id: {:system,"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"},
 secret_access_key: {:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}
```

To double check this, run the server in iex and examine this config

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=... AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=... iex -S mix phx.server
iex> Application.get_env :ex_aws, :access_key_id
```

And make sure it has the correct value.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but got

```
    iex(3)> Application.get_env :ex_aws, :access_key_id
    {:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}
```

Comment: I also tried putting in the keys themselves.  In that case, `Application.get_env` gave the expected responses, but I got `nxdomain` errors as below

```
    %{"image" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/jpeg",
   filename: "art_class_2017_05_01_bw.jpg",
   path: "/var/folders/3z/0m1z15tn6vgdpn8hsmdlv0pr0000gn/T//plug-1493/multipart-835053-356461-1"}}

    [warn] ExAws: HTTP ERROR: :nxdomain
    [warn] ExAws: HTTP ERROR: :nxdomain
    [warn] ExAws: HTTP ERROR: :nxdomain
    [warn] ExAws: HTTP ERROR: :nxdomain
```

Comment: That is what you should get. You can see here how it is used https://github.com/stavro/arc/blob/master/lib/arc/storage/s3.ex#L119

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble with code formatting -- trying both ```blah blah``` and four leading spaces.

Comment: Yes, I don't think, comments are meant for including code. you could amend your question. I'm investing the issue. Hold tight for a minute.

Comment: Have you configured your bucket? `config :arc, bucket: "exadmindemo"` I'm taking this from my [ex_admin_demo](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin_demo) project that is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143319/discussion-between-steve-pallen-and-epsilon2-7).